# Elasticsearch appends random strings to source data inside indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, kibana

I am new to Elasticsearch and have a peculiar problem: I am using elasticsearch with kibana to store and visualize most of the events in my application. For example to store a user login with user_id of 123, I would write to an index **user/login/123** with the following array as data:

```
{
   "details" : {
       "fname" : "John",
       "lname" : "Smith",
       "click" : "login-button",
        etc...
    },
    "ip_address" : 127.0.0.1,
    "browser_type" : "Chrome",
    "browser_version" : "17"
}
```

However the problem I encountered is that some records show up with a random string after the "details" array: see screenshot. Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong and how can I fix existing indexes?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxED4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have something like this in your data:

```
{
    "details" : {
       "28d211adbf" : {
          "stats" : {
             "merge_field_count": 6,
             "unsubscribe_count_since_send": 3
          }
       },
       "555cd3bcba" : {
          "stats" : {
             "merge_field_count": 6,
             "unsubscribe_count_since_send": 3
          }
       }
    },
    "ip_address" : 127.0.0.1,
    "browser_type" : "Chrome",
    "browser_version" : "17"
}
```

It's actually not a good practice in indexing document in elasticsearch.
Read about mapping explosion for more info about this:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-crash-elasticsearch#mapping-explosion

Comment: Thanks Philip, but my data **is** as I described (details is a structured object from the main app). I do not understand where those random strings are coming from... I do not want to have 28d211adbf indexes. That's why I'm asking where they're coming from... Is it elasticsearch that adds them to mitigate duplicates?

Comment: I think the problem is in the object representation in the main app. How you represent your object in your main app? The random string looks like a hashkey. Are you using hashmap or something like that in your structured object in your main app?